# current location in fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, currentlocation

I have tried many sources but I am not getting what should be used for my fragment to get the current location. 
This is my fragment:

```
 public class GMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    MapFragment fragment;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gmap, container, false);
            initilizeMap();
            return rootView;
        }
         private void initilizeMap()
        {
            MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
               if (fragment != null){
                   fragment.getMapAsync(this);

               }

        }
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        }

         @Override
        public void onPause() {

            final FragmentManager fragManager = this.getFragmentManager();
            final Fragment fragment = fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            if(fragment!=null){
                fragManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
            super.onPause();

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            final FragmentManager fragManager = this.getFragmentManager();
            final Fragment fragment = fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            if(fragment!=null){
                fragManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
            }
        }
        }
```

If anyone can help? I need a source or sample that can be used with this fragment. please help, I'm stuck here for days

Answer (score 0):

Did you have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in your Manifest file?

Also, know that if your app is running on >= API 23 device, you have to request the permission grant from the users.

Follow the official [GUIDE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config?hl=bg#specify_the_google_play_services_version_number)

### EDIT:

Do you have initialized Google Play Services?

Comment: My app is running on API 19 level, I have all the permission in Manifest file

Comment: while I am trying these lines in my onMapReady method:

Comment: I want to use GoogleApiClient but I have faced problems in this line               mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this). here I get this problem: The constructor GoogleApiClient.Builder(GMapFragment) is undefined. how to solve this???

Comment: My map works fine, I just need to add the current location feature@Seishin

Answer (score 0):

from documentation

> While enabled and the location is available

Do you have available location ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you need to gain [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) before you can comment on others’ posts to prevent abuse; why don’t you try and get some by [answering a question](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered)?

Answer (score 0):

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity()).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
```

Connect the above google api client in onStart and disconnect in onstop

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
```

Override the methods.

```
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
        }
        myLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (myLocation != null) {
            showCurrentLocation(myLocation);
            return;
        }
        if (!NetworkHelper.isGpsEnabled(getActivity()))
            PopUp.showAlertDialog(act, "Enable GPS",
                    "Help us to get your current location");
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        if (location == null)
                            return;
                        myLocation = location;
                        showCurrentLocation(location);
                    }
                });


    }
```